# Add value to tag XML Python

Tags: python, xml

I have the following problem: I have an xml file which I am parsing through xml.etree.ElementTree which has the following structure

```
<e3r>
<moreData>false</moreData>
<data>
<CashDividend Isin="IE00BYM8JD58" AdjustmentFactor="" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor=""/>
<CashDividend Isin="IE00BZ163G84" AdjustmentFactor="" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor="" Amount_Status=""/>
<CashDividend Isin="IE00BZ163H91" AdjustmentFactor="" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor=""/>
<CashDividend Isin="IE00BZ163M45 " AdjustmentFactor="" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor="" />
</data>
</e3r>
```

I am getting some data for the tag AdjustmentFactor trough an API (where I use the Isin to get the data) and what I want to achieve is to add data that I got with the API to AdjustmentFactor. (which is linked to the Isin). I somehow can't solve this.

This is how I get each ISIN:

```
isins = []

 for child in tree.getroot().getchildren()[1].getchildren():
            isins.append(child.attrib['Isin'])

 for isin in isins:
    print isin
```

But I don't know how to add data to AdjustmentFactor using the data stored in the list isins.

Can someone assist please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't stated clearly in the question, but if I understand this correctly, you want to update `AdjustmentFactor` attribute value of an element where `Isin` attribute equals certain value. You can use XPath expression like `.//element_name[@attribute_name='attribute_value']` to find element by its attribute value.

**working demo example :**

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

raw = '''<e3r>
<moreData>false</moreData>
<data>
<CashDividend Isin="IE00BYM8JD58" AdjustmentFactor="" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor=""/>
<CashDividend Isin="IE00BZ163G84" AdjustmentFactor="" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor="" Amount_Status=""/>
<CashDividend Isin="IE00BZ163H91" AdjustmentFactor="" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor=""/>
<CashDividend Isin="IE00BZ163M45 " AdjustmentFactor="" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor="" />
</data>
</e3r>'''

root = et.fromstring(raw)
isin = "IE00BYM8JD58"
adjustment_factor = "FOO"
element = root.find(".//CashDividend[@Isin='%s']" % isin)
element.set("AdjustmentFactor", adjustment_factor)

print et.tostring(root)
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/529282)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<e3r>
<moreData>false</moreData>
<data>
<CashDividend AdjustmentFactor="FOO" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor="" Isin="IE00BYM8JD58" />
<CashDividend AdjustmentFactor="" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor="" Amount_Status="" Isin="IE00BZ163G84" />
<CashDividend AdjustmentFactor="" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor="" Isin="IE00BZ163H91" />
<CashDividend AdjustmentFactor="" Adjustment_Date="" Adjustment_Factor="" Isin="IE00BZ163M45 " />
</data>
</e3r>
```